# Logging execution SQL time in Java application

Tags: java, sql

Most of the databases as well as AWS provide tools to log time for SQL’s execution.
Does it have sense  to log also from the application and how accurate is it?

I am using Apache QueryRunner that has methods for query, insert, update.  https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/QueryRunner.html

I can override every QueryRunner method adding SQL and execution time logging, i.e.:

```
@Override
public int update(String sql, Object... params) throws SQLException {
   long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
   int result = super.update(sql, params);
   long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
   logSqlWithTime(sql, startTime, endTime, params);
   return result;
}

// Log SQL execution time along with the runner's identity (if provided)
private void logSqlWithTime(String sql, long startTime, long endTime, Object... params) {
  long executionTime = endTime - startTime;
  StringBuilder logMessage = new StringBuilder(String.format("[%s] SQLExecutionTime: %d ms - SQL: %s",
          (runnerName != null) ? runnerName : "Unnamed Runner", executionTime, sql));
  if (params != null) {
     logMessage.append(Arrays.deepToString(params));
  }
  // You can log this message using your preferred logging mechanism
  //System.out.println(logMessage);
  logger.info(logMessage.toString());
}
```

How accurate will be this logging? The DB is MySQL, we also use Redshift.
Just in case the Apache QueryRunner update methods is as follows:

```
public int update(String sql, Object... params) throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = this.prepareConnection();
    return this.update(conn, true, sql, params);
}

private int update(Connection conn, boolean closeConn, String sql, Object... params) throws SQLException {
    if (conn == null) {
        throw new SQLException("Null connection");
    } else if (sql == null) {
        if (closeConn) {
            this.close(conn);
        }
        throw new SQLException("Null SQL statement");
    } else {
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        int rows = 0;
        try {
            stmt = this.prepareStatement(conn, sql);
            this.fillStatement(stmt, params);
            rows = stmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException var11) {
            this.rethrow(var11, sql, params);
        } finally {
            this.close(stmt);
            if (closeConn) {
                this.close(conn);
            }
        }
        return rows;
    }
}
```

Comment: side note: from `logMessage.append(Arrays.deepToString(params))` - be careful logging PII.

Comment: This is a generic answer: If you suspect SQL performance issues during development, logging the performance of every call may give the information you need to track down and fix the performance issues. It also may uncover "chatty" behaviors where an operation makes many more requests to the database than needed or expected. In production, I would say don't log everything. Perhaps you can set a threshold and log the occurrences of "long running queries". Often what runs quickly against small development databases hits bottlenecks once the application is deployed and accesses real-world data.